# Windows manager not booting after grub

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub

I have:

Windows 7 installed on my primary HDD 500GB

Debian 9 installed on secondary SSD 100 GB in caddy placed in CD-ROM

OUTPUT of lsblk on Debian:

```
debian:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   100M  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0   128M  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0 451.2G  0 part
└─sda4   8:4    0  14.4G  0 part
sdb      8:16   0 111.8G  0 disk
├─sdb1   8:17   0 104.3G  0 part /
├─sdb2   8:18   0     1K  0 part
└─sdb5   8:21   0   7.5G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

GRUB installed on /dev/sdb

Bios device priority is set up to boot from caddy(GRUB Debian) and then from internal HDD(WIN 7) For first, when I remove SSD (Debian), WIN7 boot normally, no problem.

When I insert SSD (Debian), GRUB shows up:

1.Option is DEBIAN

2.Option alternative with Debian  // never tried this

3.Option Windows 7
So when I select I select 1.Opinion, Debian boots up normally and everything works

PROBLEM is when I selected 3. Opinion, GRUB tried to boot WIN7 or Windows boot manager and I can hear that HDD(Win7) started to move but after few second Windows boot manager said error message (see picture):

[Windows boot manager problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbEdk.jpg)

And Windows failed to boot. Please let me know how to fix this. And I don't want to to do any changes to HDD with Win7 if it is not necessary.!

Comment: I would run `sudo update-grub` in Debian before any other troubleshooting. This is assuming Windows still boots normally if not via Grub. Otherwise you need to actually repair Wiondows, Grub cannot boot a Windows that doesn't boot from itself.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I did it yesterday, but nothing changed.... I also reinstall whole grub. And then updated it... Still same.

Comment: And windows boot from itself...but not via GRUB... I don't know why... Maybe some protection??? Laptom is ThinkPad E560